# How to Schedule Rscripts using Oozie

Tags: r, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am using Rhadoop on Hortonworks Sandbox to read data from HDFS to R and after reading that in R, I am performing certain operation on that file.

I want to schedule (daily, weekly, monthly) this R script using Oozie.

Any help is strongly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems somebody did it for you:

Here are the relevant bash script and usage instruction from [Oozie R helper on Github](https://github.com/ConduitTeam/oozie_R).

```
#!/bin/bash

die () {
    echo >&2 "$@"
    exit 1
}

[ "$#" -eq 3 ] || die "3 arguments required, $# provided"
hdfs_file=$1
r_file=$2
hdfs_output=$3

if [[  ${hdfs_output} =~ ^\/tmp\/.*$ ]]; then
    echo "I will run the r script $2 on the hdfs $1"
    tmp_filename="/tmp/`date +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S"`"
    echo "using tmp_dir $tmp_filename"
    tmp_output="/tmp/out`date +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S"`"


    hadoop fs -getmerge $hdfs_file $tmp_filename
    R -f $r_file --args $tmp_filename $tmp_output
    hadoop fs -rmr $hdfs_output
    hadoop fs -put $tmp_output $hdfs_output 

else 
  die "$hdfs_output must be in /tmp/"
fi
```

> **Oozie R helper**,
>
> The data science team wanted to be able to run R script using oozie,
>
> They wanted to be able to run ETL using Hive and on the result of that
>   ETL they wanted to run the r script.
>
> So I created a bash script that take 3 arguments: 1. The HDFS input of
>   the files they want to run 2. The R script they want to run 3. The
>   output on the hdfs where they want their result to be. (currentlt
>   because the user is mapred I allow only /tmp/)
>
> **How to run**
>
> You can use a shell oozie action like this:
>
> ```
> <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
>             <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
>             <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
>             <exec>run_r_hadoop.sh</exec>
>               <argument>/user/hive/warehouse/dual</argument>
>               <argument>count.r</argument>
>               <argument>/tmp/r_test</argument>
>             <file>count.r#count.r</file>
> </shell>
> ```
>
> **Prequesite**
>
> R and all its libraries should be installe on all Hadoop salves,
>   including all the libraries that are used